# Worklight 6.1 swift 1.2 support

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a project that has already built and deployed adapters on a worklight 6.1 server and I have to develop an app to use these adapters using the latest version of Swift.

I'm trying to add native API to the project and then connect with the server from a native app but I alwas get this error when I call WLCliend.WLConnectWithDelegate(self):

```
> 2015-07-14 17:35:58.782 iOSNativeAPI[46479:353823] [ERROR]
> [WORKLIGHT]: Cannot find Cookies.mom file 2015-07-14 17:35:58.789
> iOSNativeAPI[46479:353823] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
> exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an
> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
> *** First throw call stack:
```

My question is does this have anything with that the project is in swift and the server in 6.1? because the 6.1 server didn't generate bridging header file, I had to wirte it on my own.

so does worklight server 6.1 works with swift 1.2?
if yes what could be causing this error?

**Edit:**

here is the bridging header file: (I took it from file which is generated using the 7.0 version and hint the files which weren't found)

```
/*
* Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
* 5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2014. All Rights Reserved.
* US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
* disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
*/
#import "AbstractAcquisitionError.h"
#import "AbstractGeoAreaTrigger.h"
#import "AbstractGeoDwellTrigger.h"
#import "AbstractPosition.h"
#import "AbstractTrigger.h"
#import "AbstractWifiAreaTrigger.h"
#import "AbstractWifiDwellTrigger.h"
#import "AbstractWifiFilterTrigger.h"
#import "AcquisitionCallback.h"
#import "AcquisitionFailureCallback.h"
#import "BaseChallengeHandler.h"
#import "BaseDeviceAuthChallengeHandler.h"
//#import "BaseProvisioningChallengeHandler.h"
#import "ChallengeHandler.h"
//#import "JSONStore.h"
//#import "JSONStoreAddOptions.h"
//#import "JSONStoreCollection.h"
//#import "JSONStoreOpenOptions.h"
//#import "JSONStoreQueryOptions.h"
//#import "JSONStoreQueryPart.h"
#import "OCLogger.h"
#import "WLAcquisitionFailureCallbacksConfiguration.h"
#import "WLAcquisitionPolicy.h"
//#import "WLAnalytics.h"
#import "WLArea.h"
//#import "WLAuthorizationManager.h"
#import "WLCallbackFactory.h"
#import "WLChallengeHandler.h"
#import "WLCircle.h"
#import "WLClient.h"
#import "WLConfidenceLevel.h"
#import "WLCookieExtractor.h"
#import "WLCoordinate.h"
#import "WLDelegate.h"
#import "WLDevice.h"
#import "WLDeviceAuthManager.h"
#import "WLDeviceContext.h"
#import "WLEventSourceListener.h"
#import "WLEventTransmissionPolicy.h"
#import "WLFailResponse.h"
#import "WLGeoAcquisitionPolicy.h"
#import "WLGeoCallback.h"
#import "WLGeoDwellInsideTrigger.h"
#import "WLGeoDwellOutsideTrigger.h"
#import "WLGeoEnterTrigger.h"
#import "WLGeoError.h"
#import "WLGeoExitTrigger.h"
#import "WLGeoFailureCallback.h"
#import "WLGeoPosition.h"
#import "WLGeoPositionChangeTrigger.h"
#import "WLGeoTrigger.h"
#import "WLGeoUtils.h"
#import "WLLocationServicesConfiguration.h"
#import "WLOnReadyToSubscribeListener.h"
#import "WLPolygon.h"
#import "WLProcedureInvocationData.h"
#import "WLProcedureInvocationResult.h"
#import "WLPush.h"
#import "WLPushOptions.h"
//#import "WLResourceRequest.h"
#import "WLResponse.h"
#import "WLResponseListener.h"
//#import "WLSecurityUtils.h"
//#import "WLSimpleDataSharing.h"
#import "WLTriggerCallback.h"
#import "WLTriggersConfiguration.h"
//#import "WLTrusteer.h"
//#import "WLUserCertAuth.h"
#import "WLWifiAccessPoint.h"
#import "WLWifiAccessPointFilter.h"
#import "WLWifiAcquisitionCallback.h"
#import "WLWifiAcquisitionPolicy.h"
#import "WLWifiConnectTrigger.h"
#import "WLWifiConnectedCallback.h"
#import "WLWifiDisconnectTrigger.h"
#import "WLWifiDwellInsideTrigger.h"
#import "WLWifiDwellOutsideTrigger.h"
#import "WLWifiEnterTrigger.h"
#import "WLWifiError.h"
#import "WLWifiExitTrigger.h"
#import "WLWifiFailureCallback.h"
#import "WLWifiLocation.h"
#import "WLWifiTrigger.h"
#import "WLWifiVisibleAccessPointsChangeTrigger.h"
```

Comment: To make sure you have all the required files in your bridging header, look in the "include" folder of the WorklightAPI, and list all the .h files you can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nil connection between the fact you're implementing your application in Swift 1.2 (which is great of you to do that!) and your server. The server doesn't care about the programming language the application was written with.

And yes, you are indeed supposed to implement your own bridging header file in Worklight 6.1. In later releases this bridging file is provided for you. Later releases = MobileFirst Platform 7.0.

You are more than encouraged to upgrade from Worklight 6.1 to MobileFirst 7.0.

Also note that cookies.mom was deprecated and is no longer in use, but I believe that in 6.1 it still is in use, so right now my guess is that it may be your bridging header that may be at fault or your implementation. Can you provide either of these?

Comment: I can't upgrade the server version because I'm integrating with a third party server, I added the bridging header file, also can you please provide the 6.1 documentation? there's might be something wrong with the way I'm trying to connect @idan

Comment: I already mentioned this to Tony Al Haddad - sync up with your team members.

Comment: Thanks @IdanAdar for your appreciated help we are working on it now

Comment: Thank you @IdanAdar for your help I got the documentation from Tony and managed to call the adapters from the swift app.

Comment: @Firas, Glad to hear. Please mark as Resolved/Answered when you can.